# Reporting Services 2005: matrix plus table has not the expected width

Tags: reporting-services, rendering

I have a problem with a report that contains a matrix and a table to it´s right. The matrix contains 13 columns, the table one column. The columns are designed so that in interactive view, they have a combined width of 26.5 cm: 5.5 cm + 12 * 1.5 cm + 3cm, fitting a DinA4 page.
The report is rendered correctly in Internet Explorer 9 but in all other browsers I use (FF, Opera, Safari, all pretty much up to date), the matrix is much to slim, only stretching just about over half of the page.
Without the table right to the matrix, everything is rendered fine in all browsers.
Using a rectangle around elements didn´t help.
Has anyone perhaps had a similar issue? I use Reporting Services 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering for SSRS 2005 and ReportViewer version 9 are terrible in non-IE browsers. [MSDN recommends IE 6 or 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for viewing reports.

Starting with VS2010 and ReportViewer version 10 [browser support improved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)... a lot. I think upgrading is really your only option (short of telling your users to stick with IE).

You haven't told us *how* your users are viewing the report: through the web manager, the ReportViewer, or some other way? If it's through a ReportViewer, AFAIK you can hook up the 10.0.0.0 controls to SSRS 2005 as well.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, we use Report Viewer Version 8 (together with Visual Studio 2008). Do you think upgrading will work fine?

Comment: I'm not sure. The upgrade from 9 to 10 was near painless for us. There's only one way to find out: try it.

Comment: it seems not to work. you need sql server 2008 to get it going :(

Comment: Ah, alas. I'll have to stick with my answer I'm afraid though, meaning your only options are upgrading or telling your users they need IE.